# spring batch: Dump a set of queries over a database in parallel to flat files

Tags: csv, jdbc, spring-batch

So my scenario drilled down to the essence is as follows:
Essentially, I have a config file containing a set of SQL queries whose result sets need to be exported as CSV files.
Since some queries may return billions of rows, and because something may interrupt the process (bug, crash, ...), I want to use a framework such as spring batch, which gives me restartabilty and job monitoring.
I am using a file based H2 database for persisting spring batch jobs.

So, here are my questions:

- Upon creating a Job, I need to provide my RowMapper some initial configuration. So what happens when a job needs to be restarted after a e.g. crash? Concretly:

  - Is the state of the RowMapper automatically persisted, and upon restart Spring batch will try to restore the object from its database, or
  - will the RowMapper object be used that is part of the original spring batch XML config file, or
  - I have to maintain the RowMapper's state using the step's/job's ExecutionContext?
- Above question is related to whether there is magic going on when using the spring batch XML configuration, or whether I could as well create all these beans in a programmatic way:
  Since I need to parse my own config format into a spring batch job config, I rather just use spring batch's Java classes (beans) and fill them out appropriately, rather attempting to manually write out valid XML. However, if my Job crashes, I would create all the beans myself again. Does spring batch automagically restore the Job state from its database?
- If I really need XML, is there a way to serialize a spring-batch JobRepository (or one of these objects) as a spring batch XML config?
- Right now, I tried to configure my Step with the following code - but I am unsure if this is the proper way to do this:

  - Is TaskletStep the way to go?
  - Is the way I create the chunked reader/writer correct, or is there some other object which I should use instead?
  - I would have assumed that opening of the reader and writer would occur automatically as part of the JobExecution, but if I don't open these resources prior to running the Job, I get an exception telling me that I need to open them first. Maybe I need to create some other object that manages the resoures (jdbc connection and file handle)?

    ```
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Foobar> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Foobar>();
    itemReader.setSql(sqlStr);
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
    itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();

    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
    itemReader.open(executionContext);

    FlatFileItemWriter<String> itemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<String>();

    itemWriter.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<String>());
    itemWriter.setResource(outResource);
    itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    itemWriter.open(executionContext);


    int commitInterval = 50000;
    CompletionPolicy completionPolicy = new SimpleCompletionPolicy(commitInterval);
    RepeatTemplate repeatTemplate = new RepeatTemplate();
    repeatTemplate.setCompletionPolicy(completionPolicy);

    RepeatOperations repeatOperations = repeatTemplate;
    ChunkProvider<Foobar> chunkProvider = new SimpleChunkProvider<Foobar>(itemReader, repeatOperations);

    ItemProcessor<Foobar, String> itemProcessor = new ItemProcessor<Foobar, String>() {
    /* Custom implemtation */ };


    ChunkProcessor<Foobar> chunkProcessor = new SimpleChunkProcessor<Foobar, String>(itemProcessor, itemWriter);

    Tasklet tasklet = new ChunkOrientedTasklet<QuadPattern>(chunkProvider, chunkProcessor); //new SplitFilesTasklet();

    TaskletStep taskletStep = new TaskletStep(); 
    taskletStep.setName(taskletName);
    taskletStep.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    taskletStep.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);    

    taskletStep.setTasklet(tasklet);
    taskletStep.afterPropertiesSet();

    job.addStep(taskletStep);
    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of you questions are really complex and can be difficult give a good answer without write a long paper.
I'm new with spring-batch as you, and I found a lot of really useful info - and all the answers to your questions - reading ***Spring batch in action***: it's completed, well explained, full of example and cover all aspects of framework (reader/writer/processor, job/tasklet/chunk lifecycle/persistence, tx/resources management, job flow, integration with other service, partitioning, restarting/retry, failure management and a lot of interesting things).
Hope to help

Comment: In the mean time I managed to get Spring Batch working using Java based config. The part which was essential for my understanding was, that first, a blueprint of the workflow is created as a Java object model (either using XML or Java-based config). In this model, there are jobs and steps and each have their context. The data stored in context (plus some spring batch metadata) end up in the database - but not the blueprint itself, i.e. all the logic stays outside of the persistence, and its the developers responsibility to make sure that upon restarting a job, the same blueprint is used.